# on_member_join not triggering

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm using discord.py to write a bot. I want it to add a role named 'unverified' to all members upon joining. I don't get any error but the role just doesn't get added for some reason

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role_unverified = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="unverified")
    await member.add_roles(role_unverified)
```

Comment: Print out the role_unverified and see what it gives you.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't trigger at all

Comment: Do you have your member intents turned on and configured?

Comment: intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

that's what I have

Comment: Add a print statement at the top of the event. Does it show that it triggers? Also keep in mind if you have any exception handlers they may silently ignore any exception.

Comment: the thing is, it doesn't trigger at all. I don't have any exception handlers, so idk why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from discord.utils import get

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = get(member.guild.roles, name="unverified")
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

this should work i think

Comment: you should probably have the server members intent on

Answer (score -1):

aren't you retrieving the role from the member you're trying to assign it to?
Woulnd't it be something like

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
role_unverified = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="unverified")
await member.add_roles(role_unverified)
```

Comment: where do you get the guild object from?

Comment: nevermind I misunderstood something in their API. From what I red your code looks good. 2 things to check --> authorization, but this should through an error and (and therefore more likely) check the result of your role as Brentspine suggested. I would expect it to be empty